# Is it possible to force Scanner to return empty string?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a socket and I need to read text communication from it. Every command ends with \r\n sequence. I'm using Scanner with delimiter, like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(socket.getInputStream());
scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");

String tmp = scanner.next();
```

However I want it to return empty string if it finds just \r\n, for example, this input:

`\r\nSometext\nMoretext\r\n` should be read using two `next()` and first should return empty string `""`, second should return `Sometext\nMoretext`.

As you can see, I'm allowing `\n` inside each token, that is why using `readLine()` wouldn't work.

Right now, for this input, the first `next()` returns `Sometext\nMoretext`, ignoring the first `\r\n`. Is it possible to force it to return empty string or is there a way to detect that it skipped one `\r\n`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can by extending and cusomizing Scanner class.

you must write something like:

```
class MyScanner extends Scanner {

  @Override
  public String next() {
    String ret = super.next();
    if (ret.conatins("\r\n"); ret = "";
    return ret;
  }
}
```

Obiouvsly in your main class you must use MyScanner

**UPDATE**

As someone say, Scanner is final class, and you can't do what I've suggested. But you can Make a wrap class like this:

```
class MyScanner {
  Scanner scanner;
  String[] toClean;

  public void setToClean(String[] toClean) {
    this.toClean=toClean;
  }

  public MyScanner(InputStram in) {
    scanner = new Scanner(in);
  }

  public String next() {
    String ret=scanner.next();
    if(Arrays.asList(this.toClean).conatins(ret) ret ="";
    return ret;  
  }

}
```

in your caller class then you can use it as:

```
MyScanner mys = new MyScanner(socket.getInputStream());
String tmp=mys.next();
mys.setToClean({"bad-word","\n"});
String tmpClean=mys.next();
```

Comment: Thanks also  @Klemens Morbe